# Lookup of comma separated value in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

Would appreciate if someone could help with this excel formula:

Here's what I need:

In my excel sheet, Tab1 has this:

**Col A**        **Col B**
Red                  Lookup Formula to show 'Red' or 'Not Available'
Green           Lookup Formula to show 'Green' or 'Not Available'
Blue               Lookup Formula to show 'Blue' or 'Not Available'
Yellow         Lookup Formula to show 'Yellow' or 'Not Available'
Purple         Lookup Formula to show 'Purple' or 'Not Available'

In Tab2, Col K, I've this:

**Col K**
Red
Red, Green
Orange, Blue

Now, formula in Col B in Tab1 match against the values present in Col K of Tab2. And as soon as a match is found (does not matter if the match is found multiple times), should automatically set the value in Col B of Tab1

Otherwise, just put 'Not Available'

- So, in this case, this is what it should look like for Tab1:

**Col A**         **Col B**
Red                Red
Green           Green
Blue               Blue
Yellow           Not Available
Purple           Not Available

**Please note:**

Previously, my Tab2 had no comma separated value(csv), just 1 value in 1 cell and at that time, this formula worked fine for me:

> **=IFNA(VLOOKUP(Col1, 'Tab2'!K:K, 1, FALSE), "Not available")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Tab 1 A1 is "Red" you can place the below formula in B1 and copy down.

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Tab2'!K:K,"*"&A1&"*")>0,A1,"Not Avaiable")
```